# vscode word wrap wrapping text and code, breaking it and not indenting it in proper way

Tags: javascript, html, angular, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

word wrap not identing text and breaking lines where is no need

img here

[image: 1]

I tried to enable and disable word wrap option, installed Rewrap plugin, and experimented in vscode settings

Comment: Which code formatter are you using?

Comment: Prettier + Prettier ESLint

Answer (score 1):

Prettier wraps the lines at the setted length. And in most causes Prettier makes it good to read. In VS Code on bottom right you see the Prettier symbol. Click on it you and see what it does.

[image]

*Settings*

```
  "parser": "typescript",
  "useTabs": false,
  "tabWidth": 2,
  "singleQuote": true,
  "printWidth": 100,
  "trailingComma": "all",
  "semi": true,
  "bracketSpacing": true,
  "arrowParens": "avoid",
  "endOfLine": "lf"
}
["INFO" - 2:23:00 PM] Formatting completed in 130ms.
```

What you need is to change the Prettier settings itself. The good news: You can do it for each project, if you want! Read more about it [here](https://prettier.io/docs/en/configuration.html).

> Configuration File
> Prettier uses cosmiconfig for configuration file support. This means you can configure Prettier via (in order of precedence):

- "prettier" key in your package.json file.
- .prettierrc file written
  in JSON or YAML.  .prettierrc.json, .prettierrc.yml,
- .prettierrc.yaml, or .prettierrc.json5 file.  .prettierrc.js,
- .prettierrc.cjs, prettier.config.js, or prettier.config.cjs file that
  exports an object using module.exports.
- .prettierrc.toml file.

So create the file and set (I think) the `printWidth`.